# Referencing class instance through lists

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, class, oop

I have two classes. `Province` creates a bunch of instances of `Areas`, and puts them in its `self.areas` list. I want for an `Areas` instance to access the attributes (or other data) of the `Province` instance which contains it in its `self.areas` list. To visualize:

```
class Province:
    def __init__(self, stuff="spam"):
        self.stuff = stuff
        self.areas = list()
    def makeareas(self):
        # make instances of Areas and put them in self.areas

class Areas:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def access_stuff(self):
        # access stuff of the Province where it is in its list
```

How do I accomplish this? More importantly, is this even a correct approach? Is there a more reasonable and easier way to do this that I don't know of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When instantiating an `Area` pass it a reference to `province` like:

#### Code:

```
class Province:
    def __init__(self, stuff="spam"):
        self.stuff = stuff
        self.areas = list()

    def makeareas(self, area):
        self.areas.append(Areas(area, self))

class Areas:
    def __init__(self, area, province):
        self.area = area
        self.province = province

    def access_stuff(self):
        # access stuff of the Province where it is in its list
        return '%s - %s ' %(self.area, self.province.stuff)
```

#### Test Code:

```
p = Province('This is stuff')
# Examples
p.makeareas('area1')
p.makeareas('area2')

for area in p.areas:
    print(area.access_stuff())
```

#### Results:

```
area1 - This is stuff 
area2 - This is stuff
```

Comment: Wow, that was a very fast response. Thank you, that is exactly what I needed.